# How to delete all but one row in SQL

Tags: database, duplicates

I would like to remove all but one row but in conjunction with PHP.

I think it will be a simpler solution for my problem, which is to remove duplicate information.

Ok... I just realised what i've already done is crap.

Basically i have a table (dev_discs) and i want to search for duplicates in the column 'discReference' and then delete all but one, thus leaving the one remaining row.

Is there an easy query to do this? I came across similar situations on the net and they're all complicated... I don't think its a very complicated scenario.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? If anything but `MySQL` [one of the answers here should work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/73226) but MySQL is funny about referencing the table you are deleting from in a sub query.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to delete all the duplicates of one row? Do you want to delete all the duplicates of a group of the rows? Do you want to delete all the duplicates of all the rows of a table? Do you want to delete all the rows of a table save 1?

Comment: It would seem simplest to just a select query to create the delete queries, then just pick the one you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. 
My answer should now explain what i wanted to do.

Comment: No, you haven't told us what RDBMS you are using, but I suspect it's MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

No easy way, AFAIK. With PHP it shouldn't be too difficult though (I can think of no way you can do this easily just using SQL).

1. Create a new table with the same structure as the original one:

   CREATE TABLE dev_discs_noduplicates (
       ...
   );
2. Fetch all non-duplicated data from the original table with a GROUP clause to eliminate duplicates:

   SELECT * FROM dev_discs WHERE 1 GROUP BY dupe_col1, dupe_col2;
3. Iterate over the results and insert them to the new table:

   INSERT INTO dev_discs_noduplicates ...;
4. Delete old table

   DROP TABLE dev_discs;
5. Rename new table:

   RENAME TABLE dev_discs_nodulicates TO dev_discs;

[EDIT]

Since @xanatos rightfully remarked a possible relations loss in the database, here's an alternative solution involving SQL and PHP.

First, fetch unique rows:

```
SELECT id FROM dev_discs GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Having these in a PHP array, implode it and use in the delete query:

```
DELETE FROM dev_discs WHERE (id) NOT IN ( @arr );
```

This should take care of all the possible issues.

Comment: In the mean time you have lost all the relations you had on your table, the ACL you had on your table...

Comment: @xanatos: yes, if they are foreign keys and/or triggers, they are lost as well. I assume the OP can recreate these. Plus, he does not mention these, so it's logical that my answer does not include them either. I'm curious to know your solution, as I suspect it's bullet-proof ;).

Comment: It's quite simple :-) http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-duplicate-rows-using-row-number-partition-by-order-by.aspx You use ROW_NUMBER() and CTE to delete the duplicates. I don't write it in a response because the OP didn't specify what SQL he is using, and I DO think persons that don't follow their questions don't deserve good answers. If you want, you are free to steal it from me and from the article :-)

Comment: Interesting. Since the OP uses PHP, I assume it's most probable he's working wuth MySQL, not MSSQL. Does your solution work in MySQL, or is it MSSQL-specific?

Comment: I don't know, and I think too he is using MySQL. I don't think it works on MySQL. But if there is a primary key on his table then you should use it to delete duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM discs dd WHERE EXISTS
    ( SELECT * FROM discs d2
     WHERE d2.discReference = dd.discReference
     AND d2.rownumber < dd.rownumber
    );
```

"rownumber" is an internal id, which is supplied by your DBMS. Could be called tid, oid.

Comment: In MySQL, you cannot use select subqueries from the table you're delting from :(.